# hypergeometric 2f2 function reference

Tags: reference-request, special-functions

Could anyone suggest a reference (book or paper, no URL though) for [this identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F2/17/02/01/0008/) involving the ${}_2F_{2}$ hypergeometric function?

Answer (score 2):

Hypergeometric functions $_pF_q$ whose parameters differ by integers are said to be *contiguous*; if $p\leq q+1$ then any $q+2$ distinct contiguous functions are linearly related. See the references listed in DLMF entry [16.3(ii)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.3#ii).

Comment: I have found that many of the contiguous relations can be directly computed by "resolving" (eliminating the derivate of qFp between instances) the expanded (n=1) relations  https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.3.i .   Which in turn can be computed by examing the individual power series expansions of the terms.  This is not the totality but shows some cases of contiguous relations are general; not specialized.  There are specialized ones that would be hard to get to this way though.